# how to close dialog after animation finished?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I wont to do some animation, and close the dialog after that:

```
                const animation = el.animate([keyFrame0, keyFrame100],
                          { duration: 600, easing: 'ease-out' });
                animation.onfinish = () => ref.close(dialogResult);
```

the dialog stays open , until second click.

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhuuhy?file=app/dialog-overview-example.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe the "afterOpened" of the dialog ref and do your animation and closing there.

```
openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: "250px",
      data: { name: this.name, animal: this.animal }
    });
    dialogRef.afterOpened().subscribe(() => {
      const wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName(
        "cdk-global-overlay-wrapper"
      )[0];
      const animation = wrapper.animate([{ left: "0" }, { left: "100%" }], {
        duration: 600,
        easing: "ease-out"
      });
      animation.onfinish = () => {
        dialogRef.close();
        wrapper.style.display = 'none'
      }
    })
  }
```

If you want to have a timeout before animating, you can you can use the "setTimeout" function.